# make/cc not finding header file even though its directory is present in PATH variable

Tags: c++, macos, path, include, makefile

I am trying to run Allegro on my mac but I keep getting

> main.cpp:1:10: fatal error:'allegro5/allegro.h' file not found

error.

I have installed allegro successfully and I can find the header files in /usr/local/include/allegro5 . I added a path to my environment variable and when I do echo $PATH I can see /usr/local/include. In the sample program I am trying to run the include is like this -

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
```

and I run-

```
make main
```

I can see the header files I have included, why isn't mac able to find the files present in that path?

Comment: `PATH` is for finding executables, not include files.

Comment: You could check `C_INCLUDE_PATH` or `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` or `INCLUDE_PATH` (not sure which it's looking for). As @PaulR mentioned, `PATH` is where the shell looks for commands, not for where the compiler looks for includes. You could also add the `-I/usr/local/include` option to your command line as a way to resolve it.

Comment: @mbratch I will try those and update you. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @mbratch I tried everything you said and the one that worked was setting CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include . So thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @PaulR mentioned, `PATH` is where the shell looks for commands, not for where the compiler looks for includes. You could also add the `-I/usr/local/include` option to your command line as a way to resolve it.

You could check `C_INCLUDE_PATH` or `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` or `INCLUDE_PATH` (not sure which it's looking for).